# Poweroff Ubuntu without sudo, without password, over SSH

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and trying to execute "poweroff" as a sudoer but without needing to enter the password.

I added this line to visudo:

```
nurp    ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

It gives this error:

```
nurp@nurp-OptiPlex-7040:~$ poweroff
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to power off system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

I tried `sudo poweroff -f` but then it asks for password.
I just want to run a long script and poweroff after it finishes. I don't want to type password on the command line.

Comment: have you tried all alternatives here ? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=963124

Comment: Interesting because your line looks correct, and I replace nurp with alvin it works here.

Comment: This is the correct syntax - maybe you have some other error in your sudores file? you can check as root with 'visudo -c'

Comment: I don't need root privileges to use the `poweroff`-command.

Comment: @mook765 In the console, yes, but the original poster connects through ssh.

Comment: @RobertRiedl It's unlikely he has other syntax error, because he uses visudo and will reject it.

Comment: @AlvinLiang, right ! I didn't catch that.

Comment: setting the sticky bit works also `sudo chmod a+s /sbin/poweroff`

Comment: There's a difference between running `poweroff` at a console vs. via SSH: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1005914/19626. While a different question, it's the same answer.

Comment: @user535733's link was the correct duplicate for my question. Could someone edit the link above the question? I can't do it somehow.